# Find the area of two functions in wolfram mathematica

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, area, curve, wolframalpha

I am having problems with drawing the area which is between two curves f(X)=-(x-2)^2+4 and g(x)=x/x+1 which says that the area is in the FIRST quadrant.
Then to calculate the area of the area.Here is my code in wolfram mathematica.

```
f[x_] = -(x - 2)^2 + 4;
g[x_] = x/x + 1;
Plot[f[x] - g[x], {x, , }]
Integrate[f[x]-g[x],{x,,}]
```

.Thank you

Comment: What has to be in the first quadrant?

Comment: @TijanaLazarova I reverted your last edit. Please don't "erase" a question that folks have put time into answering (Though evidently none to your liking )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f[x_] := -(x - 2)^2 + 4
g[x_] := x/x + 1
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -1 , 5}]
```

[image]

```
sol = NSolve[f[x] == g[x], x]
```

> {{x -> 0.585786}, {x -> 3.41421}}

```
{a, b} = x /. sol
```

> {0.585786, 3.41421}

```
Integrate[f[x] - g[x], {x, a, b}]
```

> 3.77124

Answer (score 0):

First I typed:

```
 -(x - 2)^2 + 4 = x/(x+1)
```

to find out where they meet.

Then:

```
area inside the curves y = -(x - 2)^2 + 4 and y = x/(x+1) for x from 0 to 3/2 + sqrt(21)/2
```

Comment: Simply solution of this equation. I needed to know how it looks like and what x should be. The area would be unbound, if x were from 0 to infinity, that is why I looked for it.

Comment: "Please close your question by clicking the check to the left of the answer that helped you most."

Answer (score 0):

The `g[x_] := x/x + 1` function looks odd. 
Given the precedence rules, x/x will simplify to 1, and x/x + 1 will thus have constant value 2 (*i.e.* 1+1).

Did you mean

```
g[x_] := x/(x+1)
```

instead ?

To display the surface between the two curves, you can use the Filling option for the Plot function :

```
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -1, 5}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

With the modified `g[x_]` function above this gives 
[Area between two curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGzld.png)

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
 Clear[f, g, k]
 f[x_] := -(x - 2)^2 + 4
 g[x_] := x/x + 1
 k[x_] := f[x] - g[x]
 roots = x /. Solve[f[x] == g[x], {x}];
 RegionMeasure[{x, k[x]}, {{x, First[roots], Last[roots]}}]
```

Out:

```
 1/2 (6 Sqrt[2] + ArcSinh[2 Sqrt[2]])
```